# Scrolling issue in googlemaps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have an html marker with an custom overlay view: But when I use it on tablet, I cannot drag around the map because it scrolls the page because it is an html marker. Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

Here is a fiddle: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/15gLv3as/6/)

what I try to do is this:

```
 if ($('.marker-cluster').length) {
        $('.marker-cluster').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 return false;
        })
```

Now  try to view in tablet with chrome and stand on the marker and drag around the map. You'll see that the page is scrolling.

Comment: I did not notice any scrolling issue in your jsfiddle link, problem occurs just in tablet ?

Comment: Yes and thats the problem IN TABLET

Comment: @Jo_bast Do you see what I mean when you switch to viewport tablet?